# Does mysql.createConnection() create an object?

Tags: mysql, node.js

In this Node.js example from W3school, does `createConnection()` create a new object?

If yes, how object isn't created in one of the ways we create a new object; not object literal, not by using `new`  keyword, not by using `object.create()`.

If no, what's `con.connect()`? Isn't `connect()` a method of `con` object ?

Example :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the mysql code, you will see `createConnection` helps set configuration for mysql connection and returns the connection object. You don't need to create a new object as it returns one.

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});
```

`createConnection` is a function which uses new operator and returns the connection object. It will return the new object every time you call it.

> If no, what's con.connect()? Isn't connect() a method of con object ?

Yes, it is a method on con object which is attached on its prototype. So, all the connection object will have it.

Also, I recommend you checking this link, it is the `index.js` of mysql npm package and look how it is returning new connection object.